# Get request info in view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

Is it possible in Zend View helper (`extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract`) get info about module/controller/action in which that helper was called ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes. You can use `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()` within view helpers. So you could do something like this:

```
class App_Helper_DoSomething extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        return Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
            ->getRequest()
            ->getControllerName();
    }
}
```

Which will print the current controller name when called in your view with:

```
echo $this->doSomething();
```

Comment: how would you get the module name? is that possible?

Comment: chrisjlee : Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getModuleName();